# Looping a script every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering how to loop a script every x seconds. I'm relatively new to javascript and jquery, however I do know how to use some of it in HTML.

I'm trying to make this script run every 34 seconds, however I don't know how to loop it as such.

Here's my script:

```
function byId(id){
  return document.getElementById(id)
}
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt) {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    byId('audioID').play() 
  }, 13000);
}
```

However I don't know how I would loop this every 34 seconds, after it starts at 13 seconds.

Thanks!

Comment: Look up `setInterval(fn, interval_in_ms)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setTimeout` makes the script run after `x` miliseconds, if you want to run the script multiple times, you need to use `setInterval` instead.

```
setInterval( function(){ byId('audioID').play() }, 34000 );
```

If I understand correctly, you want to start the interval after 34 seconds, so you need to do this instead:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //Declaring the function within this code scope just for DRY purposes
    var runFn = function(){
        byId('audioID').play();
    }
    runFn(); //runs the function once before the interval starts.
    setInterval(runFn, 34 * 1000 );
}, 13 * 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that!

Comment: @collapsar, if you look at the times, I have put this answer up 16 seconds before his comment.

Comment: @phiter: I might have missed a refresh, It's moot by now anyway since you've added content.

Comment: Sorry, I tend to do that sometimes (answer and then enhance content later).

Comment: No need to apologize. It's much better than leaving imperfect/incomplete  answers untended.

Comment: This script starts after 47 seconds (13 seconds and 34 seconds combined). How do I make it start after 13 seconds, and then make it run every 34 seconds from that point on?

Comment: Worked just like I wanted it to, thanks a lot!
If you know of any good places to learn javascript, I'd love to check them out!

Comment: If you're still learning the basics, you can try codeacademy. I've used it to learn the basics when I first started learning web development. But afterwards, the best way to learn is to practice.

Answer (score 2):

**Create a new function who will execute `byId('audioID').play()` every 34Secs**

```
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt) {}

function byId(id) {
  console.log(id);
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

const loopTime = 34000; //34000 ms = 34secs

var startProcess = function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    byId('audioID').play();
  }, loopTime);
};

setTimeout(startProcess, 13000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. If you need to stop the interval just call `clearInterval(interval)`.

```js
var interval;
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Started interval after 1 sec");
    interval = setInterval(function(){
                    console.log("hai")},2000)
                },1000);
```